# Deferred execution again: Local instance of Random inside LINQ query/queries

Tags: c#, linq, deferred-execution

I wish to understand the following behaviour I stumbled across today. This small program showcases the "problem":

```
class Bar
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
}

class Foo
{
  public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
  private static IEnumerable<Bar> bars;
  private static IEnumerable<Foo> foos;

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Random rng = new Random();
    bars = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(i => new Bar { ID = i });
    foos = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => new Foo
    {
      Bar = bars.First(b => b.ID == rng.Next(5) + 1)
    });
    var result = foos.ToList();
  }
}
```

This code does not work; it throws an `InvalidOperationException` saying "sequence does not contain a matching element".

However, once I calculate the random integer beforehand, it does work as expected:

```
var f = new List<Foo>();
for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
{
  int r = rng.Next(5) + 1;
  f.Add(new Foo
  {
    Bar = bars.First(b => b.ID == r)
  });
}
foos = f;
```

As the title states, I suspect deferred execution to be the reason for this. But I'd be glad if anyone could pinpoint the problem with the first code and explain the exact reason behind this.

(Anecdote: `rng.Next(1) + 1` *does* work, but I guess that the compiler is smart enough to replace this with the constant `1`.)

Comment: Please give a code example which actually compiles - you can't assign to a readonly field within the `Main` method...

Comment: Try to add `ToList()` at the end of `bars` linq.

Comment: your code won't even compile when you're setting those readonly fields outside your constructor.

Comment: @JonSkeet & Sam I am: I'm very sorry, that was a copy/paste error because I had 2 nearly identical console applications to test in the background. The actual example was just missing those `readonly` fields (iirc; I can't check right now). I'll edit accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're testing against different IDs each time you evaluate the predicate.

You don't need `foos` at all for this. You can just have:

```
var bar = bars.First(b => b.ID == rng.Next(5) + 1);
```

That will execute the predicate up to 5 times - one per element of `bar` - generating a new ID to test against each time. In other words, it's something like this:

```
public Bar FindRandomBarBroken(IEnumerable<Bar> bars, Random rng)
{
    foreach (var bar in bars)
    {
        if (bar.ID == rng.Next(bar.Count) + 1)
        {
            return bar;
        }
    }
    throw new Exception("I didn't get lucky");
}
```

Whereas you want something like:

```
public Bar FindRandomBarFixed(IEnumerable<Bar> bars, Random rng)
{
    // Only generate a single number!
    int targetId = rng.Next(bar.Count) + 1;
    foreach (var bar in bars)
    {
        if (bar.ID == targetId)
        {
            return bar;
        }
    }
    throw new Exception("Odd - expected there to be a match...");
}
```

You can fix this using another `Select` call to generate the random ID:

```
foos = Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
                 .Select(_ => rng.Next(5) + 1)
                 .Select(id => new Foo { Bar = bars.First(b => b.ID == id) } );
```

Note that you may well now get multiple `Bar` instances with the same ID, due to the lazy evaluation of `bars` - you probably want a `ToList()` call at the end of the assignment to `bars`.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it perfectly! A small typo above I guess: Both the "working" and "broken" method are named `FindRandomBarBroken`.

Comment: @InvisiblePanda: Whoops, fixed the method name.